# Needs to delete a line that matches with string from log file

Tags: php

I am new to php,  I am trying to delete a line from log file that matches with some string value.

I am using below code that deletes a line from log file. But unfortunately, its not working as expected. So, could anyone help me on this.

**Here is code:**

```
function search_and_delete($_file,$search_string){
        $search_string = "c";
        $file = file($_file);
        foreach ($file as $line_index => $line) {
            if(strpos($line, $search_string) !== false){
                unset($file[$line_index]);
                break;
            }
        }       
        file_put_contents($_file, implode("",$file));
}

search_and_delete("/var/a.log","hml3");
```

**Lines in log file:**

```
john abraham hml3
john abraham hml1
```

$search_string = 'hml3'

Comment: What is not working? For one, you pass `$search_string` to the function, but overwrite it with `$search_string = "c";` And second, remove the `break`. It breaks out of the `foreach`, stopping the loop.

Comment: This may not help you but PHP is not really the best candidate IMO for processing large text files. Python or Perl are much better suited to doing this job. The above comments from @Michel seem valid though. Also watch out for strpos I don't think it's UTF8 safe and will give you partial matches so hml3 will also match html321

Comment: @Catharsis. Two times right, but OP is asking for PHP, so PHP it will be :-) About the multibyte safe comparison: `mb_strpos` ([manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strpos.php)) would do the job, if `mb_internal_encoding` is set to the right encoding.